# C# Обработка текста. Как оптимизировать код и сделать его читабельнее, красивее?

Tags: c#, .net, оптимизация, инспекция-кода, рефакторинг

**Как оптимизировать код?  Можно ли сделать быстрее? Можно ли придумать  n^2 алгоритм для функции `ParseSentences`? Есть ли другой способ записать предложения более логичный и простой чем `GetSentencesWithWords`? Правильно ли выбраны типы переменных или можно что-то выбрать более подходящее? Ищу все свои косяки**

> Метод `ParseSentences` должен делать следующее: Разделять текст на
> предложения, а предложения на слова.
>
> 1. Считайте, что слова состоят только из букв (используйте метод `char.IsLetter`) или символа апострофа `'` и отделены друг от друга
>    любыми другими символами.
> 2. Предложения состоят из слов и отделены друг от друга одним из следующих символов `.!?;:()` Приводить символы каждого слова в нижний
>    регистр.
> 3. Пропускать предложения, в которых не оказалось слов.
>
> Метод должен возвращать список предложений, где каждое предложение —
> это список из одного или более слов в нижнем регистре.

```
        using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    public static class SentencesParserTask
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text1 = "B.C.D";
            Console.WriteLine("The origin string: \n" + text1);
            var sentences = new List<List<string>>();
                sentences = ParseSentences(text1);
            Console.Write("The result string: ");
            foreach (var sentence in sentences)
            {
                foreach (var word in sentence)
                {
                    Console.Write(word + " ");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nexpected result: b c d");

            var text2 = "b;\tc;\rd;\ne;\r\nf;\r\n\r\ng";

            sentences = ParseSentences(text2);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nThe origin string: \n" + text2);
            Console.Write("The result string: ");

            foreach (var sentence in sentences)
            {
                foreach (var word in sentence)
                {
                    Console.Write(word + " ");
                }
            }

            Console.Write("\nexpected result: b c d e f g");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static List<List<string>> ParseSentences(string text)
        {
            var wordsList = new List<List<string>>();
            List<string> actualSentences = GetSentencesWithWords(text);
            for (int j = 0; j < actualSentences.Count; j++)
            {
                wordsList.Add(new List<string>());
                for (int i = 0; i < actualSentences[j].Length; i++)
                {
                    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder("");
                    while (i < actualSentences[j].Length &&
                    (char.IsLetter(actualSentences[j][i]) || actualSentences[j][i] == '\''))
                    {
                        word.Append(char.ToLower(actualSentences[j][i]));
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(word.ToString()))
                        wordsList[j].Add(word.ToString());
                }
            }
            return wordsList;
        }

        public static List<string> GetSentencesWithWords(string text)
        {
            List<string> resultSentences = new List<string>();
            char[] separators = new char[] { ';', ':', '.', '!', '?', '(', ')' };
            string[] sentences;
            sentences = text.Split(separators);
            for (int i = 0; i < sentences.Length; i++)
            {
                foreach (var symbol in sentences[i])
                    if (char.IsLetter(symbol) || symbol == '\'')
                    {
                        resultSentences.Add(sentences[i]);
                        break;
                    }
            }
            return resultSentences;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если нужна инспекция, нужно как-то этот код запустить. Данный фрагмент кода, если есть вставить в проект даже не скомпилируется (вы отрубили верхнюю часть кода), так как содержит синтаксические ошибки. К тому же пример надо дополнить примером данных и кодом, который запускает указанные методы.

Comment: @aepot , Инспекцию не я подставил в теги, я пока не знаю что она за собой подразумевает. Я пока знакомлюсь с Этикетом StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот вам даже меньше, чем `N ^ 2`, шаблон проектирования "конечный автомат".

Специально избегал использования Linq

```
static List<List<string>> ParseSentences(string text)
{
    var result = new List<List<string>>();

    List<string> sentence = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (char.IsLetter(c) || c == '\'')
            sb.Append(char.ToLower(c));
        else
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
            {
                sentence.Add(sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();
            }

            if (";:.!?()".Contains(c) && sentence.Count > 0)
            {
                result.Add(sentence);
                sentence = new List<string>();
            }
        }
    }
    if (sb.Length > 0)
        sentence.Add(sb.ToString());
    if (sentence.Count > 0)
        result.Add(sentence);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Как я понимаю код прекрасен. Есть небольшая проблема . Я не уточнил, и в задании не учтено но в тестах к нему есть такой момент: конец текста может не иметь символ из сепаратора, то есть заканчиваться без любого символа и в последний вложенный if надо внести правку if((IsSeparator(c) || IsEndOfTheText) && sentence.Count > 0). Пока не понял как с foreach по символам это сделать, интересно. как оформить это условие

Comment: И отдельно хотел спросить. Я внес правку чтобы программа запускалась и с примерами. Достаточно ли они показательны? И стоит ли как то их по-другому оформлять?

Comment: @Sheeba334 _Я внес правку чтобы программа запускалась и с примерами._ - да, так лучше

Comment: у меня тесты не проходят и последнее предложение не записывает. И по логике не пролазит также. Если сепаратор и  предложение со словами. Ну так предложение может быть не пустым но не встретился сепаратор

Comment: @Sheeba334 поправил код в ответе

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, понравился ваш вариант. Есть интересные моменты. Очень благодарен за ваше уделённое время и внимание

Comment: @Sheeba334 обновил код, сделал покороче

Comment: Посмотрю метод Contains, круто, спасибо