# Как сделать сортировку массива по алфавиту, введённого через textbox C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] strArr = new string[]
    {
        textBox1.Text
    };
    Array.Sort(strArr, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
    foreach (string item in strArr)
    {
        textBox2.Text = strArr[0];
    }
}
```

После ввода слов в первый `TextBox` и нажатия на кнопку введённые слова выводятся, но не сортируются во втором `TextBox`.

Comment: Что за `TextBox`? Winforms?

Comment: Да, Windows Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все намного проще

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = textBox1.Lines;
    Array.Sort(lines, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
    textBox2.Lines = lines;
}
```

Каждое слово в новой строке должно быть.

Если слова через пробел без новых строк, тогда можно так

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] words = textBox1.Text.Split();
    Array.Sort(words, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
    textBox2.Text = string.Join(" ", words);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, а как сделать так, что бы после каждого выведенного слова был пробел?

Comment: @Фикус дополнил ответ

Comment: Большое вам спасибо.

Comment: Извините, а как сделать ваш код без использования методов?

Comment: @Фикус ничего не понял, возможно вы имеете в виду, как распарсить строку, тогда как-то так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1469416/373567

Comment: Извините, не правильно сформулировал вопрос. Как ваш код переделать под то же условие, но только без использования методов?

Comment: @Фикус легче не стало